# Removing pixelated edges from svg image

Tags: svg

I have got an SVG image which I need to put in the header of my webpage. The edges of the image are pixelated and this bothers me. Now my question is if there is some kind of way to remove these pixelated edges from the SVG. Below is an example of my SVG.

[image: example of svg]

The orange part is the SVG image I'm talking about.

Comment: The point of an SVG image is that the pixelation should not happen, as long as the image was a vector drawing to begin with. Maybe you can try exporting the image again. Otherwise you can look into anti-aliasing.

Comment: "Should not happen" is overstating it.  the anti-aliasing that happens in vector renderers is fantastic, but it can't perform miracles.  High contrast edges at shallow angles can still produce "jaggy" edges.

Comment: Having said that, the bottom edge of your orange shape doesn't look like it has ben properly antialiased.  But it may have been affected by whatever you used to capture the screen shot.  To help us figure it out, you should post the SVG you are using (or at least the appropriate part of it)

Comment: This is not really a programming question. Save the image you have as an SVG and the problem will go away.

Answer (score 6):

Check the [`shape-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering) attributes of your SVG objects. The default setting should look pretty smooth, but with `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` it's going to look a bit jagged.

```html
<svg width="300" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
  <path d="M-10 0 C 100 70 200 50 310 40" stroke="orange" fill="transparent"
        stroke-width="60" shape-rendering="auto"/>
  <text x="10" y="90">(auto)</text>
</svg>
<svg width="300" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
  <path d="M-10 0 C 100 70 200 50 310 40" stroke="orange" fill="transparent"
        stroke-width="60" shape-rendering="crispEdges"/>
  <text x="10" y="90">(crispEdges)</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: I was getting desperate with background images leaking thru SVG edges.
Fixed now, thanks!